# How to offset/shift grid position of plot using Matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a presence-absence pattern plot for a project. Unfortunately, the grid I currently have is originating its' lines in the label ticks, resulting in presence-boxes, that sit right on the grid's nodes. That is rather confusing to look at, especially with a huge dataset.

Does anyone know how to offset the position of the grid by half a step?

[Picture of the plot]
[image: 1]

Comment: The documentation doesn't specify enough, but there is a `data` keyword argument to the `grid` function (see API: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html) that may allow you to manually set the grid positions. Your x-axis are strings, but they have numeric values starting at either 0 or 1. This may not work if you want the plot to be dynamic. If your plot will be static only, you can always draw the grid manually.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not clear what you are trying to achieve from the j do you have given us.  Please make a minimal self contained example.